# How to put this specific constructor into a FactoryGirl object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am trying to put that creation code into a FactoryGirl.

So basically here, you can see my class User has a Method to create a Picture from his informations, id, created_at, etc....

.

```
class User 
has_many :pictures

def create_picture
    picture = Picture.new(
        user_id: self.id,
        store_dir: get_user_medias_path,
    )
    picture.save!
    picture
end

def get_user_media_path
   "u/#{self.id}/#{self.created_at}
end


end
```

so then I tried to put that into a FactoryGirl object, this looked as follow

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |i| "flav_#{i}" }
  end

  factory :picture do
    store_dir user.get_user_medias_path
    remote_url "http://lorempixel.com/600/600/animals/internet#{user.id}/"
    association :user     
  end
end
```

But as you would expect, he cannot find neither the user.id or the user.method.

How am I supposed to be able to reference the user attribute inside the picture object ?

I am lost. Any help would be more than welcomed. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `user` is called in the context of factory definition, which doesn't have such method. You need to call `user` on object actually being built, picture.

To do so, you should wrap computed values in blocks:

```
factory :picture do
  store_dir { user.get_user_medias_path }
  remote_url { "http://lorempixel.com/600/600/animals/internet#{user.id}/" }
  association :user     
end
```

See [lazy](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#lazy-attributes) and [dependent](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#dependent-attributes) attributes in docs.